# sendmail: specify "from" sender with hyphen in domain

Tags: sendmail

seems like this fails silently on all Linux systems I can access:

```
echo "Hola" | sendmail -i -f from@hyphenated-domain.com [my e-mail address here]
```

It works when I remove the hyphen. Do you also encounter this problem? What might be the reason for that strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to encapsulate the email in quotes like so:

```
echo "Hola" | sendmail -i -f "from@hyphenated-domain.com" [my e-mail address here]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not work either. Could it be that I have to configure the DNS server in a special way to make this work? It seems that it's impossible to send from an inexistent domain, too (means: specify it as sender)...

Comment: could you provide smtp transcript? `(echo "subject: Hola";echo;echo "Hola") | sendmail -v -i -f from@hyphenated-domain.com [my e-mail address here]`